# Minimum Sum Path of Pyramid with Data Structures

Tags: java, tree

I have a program that uses ArrayLists to store a pyramid that has been read by a txt file and calculates the minimum sum value of travelling from the top of the pyramid to the bottom.

My code's main method is like this:

```
File file1 = new File(args[0]);
Scanner reader = new Scanner(file1); // The Scanner that is going to read file1.
try {
    int pyramidSize = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Pyramid Size = " + pyramidSize);
    ArrayList<ArrayList <Integer>> solution1List = new ArrayList<ArrayList <Integer>>(pyramidSize);

    // Reads all integers to an array list.
    for(int i = 0; i < pyramidSize; i++) {
        solution1List.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
    int row = 0;
    int ctr = 0;
    int rowCounter = 1;

    while(reader.hasNext()) {

        if(reader.hasNextInt()) {    

            while(row < rowCounter) {  
                int temporaryForSolution1Integer = reader.nextInt();
                solution1List.get(ctr).add(temporaryForSolution1Integer);
                row++;
            }
            row = 0;
            ctr++;
            rowCounter++;
        }
        else {
            reader.next();
            row++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Triangle size is = " + solution1List.size());
    System.out.println("The minimum sum path is = " + minimumSumPath(solution1List));
```

And my method for calculating the sum is like this:

```
public static int minimumSumPath(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> triangle) {

    if (triangle.size() == 0)
        return 0;

    int size = triangle.size();
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int[] sum = new int[size];
    sum[0] = triangle.get(0).get(0);

    for(int current = 1; current <= size - 1; current++) {
        int next_size = triangle.get(current).size();

        for(int next = next_size - 1; next >= 0; next--) {
            if (next == 0) { // Sum[0] gets done by walking the leftmost direct way.
                sum[0] = sum[0] + triangle.get(current).get(next);
            } 
            else if (next == (next_size - 1)) { // Reaches to the rightmost element of that iteration
                sum[next] = sum[next-1] + triangle.get(current).get(next);
            } 
            else { // Provides sum[next] to be the minimal sum that can come there
                sum[next] = Math.min(sum[next-1], sum[next]) + triangle.get(current).get(next);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(sum[i] < min) {
           min = sum[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

My code is working properly. But I wonder if I can do this by implementing with a kind of Tree Data Structure (or other data structure but I thought maybe it could be done with a Tree but I couldn't figure which kind of Tree?). Any advice? I would appreciate any help and recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by creating my own Tree. Here is how it is:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
public class SolutionTree {

    SolutionNode root;

    public SolutionTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public void addRoot(int rootValue) {
        root = new SolutionNode(rootValue);
    }

    // New Node Adder
    public void addSolutionNode(int newNodeValue) {
        SolutionNode newNode = new SolutionNode(newNodeValue);
        SolutionNode newNodeRoot = breadth(root);
        if(newNodeRoot.getChildLeft() == null) {
            newNodeRoot.setChildLeft(newNode);
            newNode.setParentLeft(newNodeRoot);
        }
        else if(newNodeRoot.getChildRight() == null) {
            newNodeRoot.setChildRight(newNode);
            newNode.setParentLeft(newNodeRoot);
            if(newNodeRoot != root) {
                    if(newNodeRoot.getParentLeft().getChildRight().getChildLeft() == null) {
                        newNodeRoot.getParentLeft().getChildRight().setChildLeft(newNode);
                        newNode.setParentRight(newNodeRoot.getParentLeft().getChildRight());
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    // Node Class of Solution Tree
    protected class SolutionNode {

        private int value;
        private SolutionNode parentLeft;
        private SolutionNode parentRight;
        private SolutionNode childLeft;
        private SolutionNode childRight;

        // Constructor
        public SolutionNode() {
            value = 0;
            parentLeft = null;
            parentRight = null;
            childLeft = null;
            childRight = null;
        }

        // Constructor
        public SolutionNode(int v) {
            value = v;
            parentLeft = null;
            parentRight = null;
            childLeft = null;
            childRight = null;
        }

        // MODIFIERS

        public void setValue(int val) {
            value = val;
        }

        public void setParentLeft(SolutionNode leftParent) {
            parentLeft = leftParent;
        }

    public void setParentRight(SolutionNode rightParent) {
        parentLeft = rightParent;
    }

        public void setChildLeft(SolutionNode leftChild) {
            childLeft = leftChild;
        }

        public void setChildRight(SolutionNode rightChild) {
            childRight = rightChild;
        }

        //ACCESSORS

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public SolutionNode getParentLeft() {
            return parentLeft;
        }

        public SolutionNode getParentRight() {
            return parentRight;
        }

        public SolutionNode getChildLeft() {
            return childLeft;
        }

        public SolutionNode getChildRight() {
            return childRight;
        }




    }

    // function to compute the minimum sum path
    // It only returns the sum of the values of nodes on the min sum path 
    int minSumPath(SolutionNode current) {
        if(current == null)
            return 0;

        int sum = current.getValue();

        int left_sum = minSumPath(current.childLeft);
        int right_sum = minSumPath(current.childRight);

        if(left_sum <= right_sum) {
            sum += minSumPath(current.childLeft);
        }
        else {
            sum += minSumPath(current.childRight);
        }

        return sum;
    }

    // Breadth First Traversal
    public static SolutionNode breadth(SolutionNode root) {
        Queue<SolutionNode> queue = new LinkedList<SolutionNode>() ;
        if (root == null)
            return null;
        queue.clear();
        queue.add(root);
       while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            SolutionNode node = queue.remove();
            if(node.childLeft != null) 
                queue.add(node.childLeft);
            if(node.childRight != null) 
                queue.add(node.childRight);
            if(node.childLeft == null || node.childRight == null)
                return node;
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

I am invoking minSumPath at the main of my file reading program.

Have a nice day.